# How do we reconcile Aaron’s eternal priesthood with Jesus’ priesthood?

Tags: contradiction, exodus, hebrews, intertextuality

**Q: How do we reconcile these verses?**

> “You shall anoint them, as you anointed their father, that they may
> minister to Me as priests; for their anointing shall surely be an
> ***everlasting priesthood throughout their generations***.”” ‭‭Exodus‬
> ‭40:15‬

Vs.

> “(for they have become priests without an oath, but He with an oath by Him who said to Him: “The Lord has sworn
> And will not relent, ‘You are a priest forever According to the order
> of Melchizedek’ ”), by so much more Jesus has become a surety of a
> better covenant.” ‭‭Hebrews‬ ‭7:21-22

‬ ‭I was in a debate with a Jewish person, and I am confused with these 2 texts.

So, isn’t the argument already in Hebrews 7?  Some sort of annulment?  Can someone elaborate how these aren’t in conflict?  It seem that we have 2 eternal priesthoods??

Answer (score 2):

Between Exodus 40 and Hebrews 7 we have **1 Samuel 2** where we read:

**27 And there came a man of God unto Eli, and said unto him, Thus saith the LORD, Did I plainly appear unto the house of thy father** (Aaron the Levite)**, when they were in Egypt in Pharaoh's house?**
**28 And did I choose him** (Aaron the Levite) **out of all the tribes of Israel to be my priest, to offer upon mine altar, to burn incense, to wear an ephod before me? and did I give unto the house of thy father** (Aaron the Levite) **all the offerings made by fire of the children of Israel?
29 Wherefore kick ye at my sacrifice and at mine offering, which I have commanded in my habitation; and honourest thy sons above me, to make yourselves fat with the chiefest of all the offerings of Israel my people?
30 Wherefore the LORD God of Israel saith, I said indeed that thy house, and the house of thy father** (descendants of Aaron the Levite)**, should walk before me for ever: but now the LORD saith, Be it far from me; for them that honour me I will honour, and they that despise me shall be lightly esteemed.
31 Behold, the days come, that I will cut off thine arm, and the arm of thy father's house** (house of Aaron the Levite)**, that there shall not be an old man in thine house.
32 And thou shalt see an enemy in my habitation, in all the wealth which God shall give Israel: and there shall not be an old man in thine house for ever.
33 And the man of thine, whom I shall not cut off from mine altar, shall be to consume thine eyes, and to grieve thine heart: and all the increase of thine house shall die in the flower of their age.
34 And this shall be a sign unto thee, that shall come upon thy two sons, on Hophni and Phinehas; in one day they shall die both of them.
35And I will raise me up a faithful priest, that shall do according to that which is in mine heart and in my mind: and I will build him a sure house; and he shall walk before mine anointed for ever.
36And it shall come to pass, that every one that is left in thine house shall come and crouch to him for a piece of silver and a morsel of bread, and shall say, Put me, I pray thee, into one of the priests' offices, that I may eat a piece of bread.**

In it, God pronounces not only the judgement of the corrupted house of Eli, but also the whole Levitical priesthood. It wouldn't make sense to mention Aaron so many times otherwise. Notice also the similarities of the verse 35 to **2 Samuel 7:13**:

**12 And when thy days be fulfilled, and thou shalt sleep with thy fathers, I will set up thy seed after thee, which shall proceed out of thy bowels, and I will establish his kingdom.
13 He shall build an house for my name, and I will stablish the throne of his kingdom for ever.**

They are similar on purpose, both messianic and talk about Jesus.

Later on, **Zechariah** merges the messianic king and the high priest together in the **6**th chapter of his book:

**11 Then take silver and gold, and make crowns, and set them upon the head of Joshua the son of Josedech, the high priest;
12 And speak unto him, saying, Thus speaketh the LORD of hosts, saying, Behold the man whose name is The BRANCH; and he shall grow up out of his place, and he shall build the temple of the LORD:
13 Even he shall build the temple of the LORD; and he shall bear the glory, and shall sit and rule upon his throne; and he shall be a priest upon his throne: and the counsel of peace shall be between them both.**

1 Samuel 2:36 also proves that salvation (pictured as silver) and sustaining of life (pictured by bread) for all including the Levitical priesthood will come only through that new eternal high priest. And the priests under Him will be appointed based on His mercy, not because of their genealogy.

Comment: +1 This is good! But if you wouldn't mind a little advice, so much bold hurts my eyes, and the question could do with improved formatting. For example, you don't need to include all of scriptures you cite but can excerpt from them.

Comment: Sorry for that. I was writing in the middle of the night, so it looked OK to my tired eyes.

Comment: @ארקדיוס If your answer is the case, does that mean the term “everlasting priesthood throughout their generations” means that the generations of Aaron’s priesthood are over?  As you argued, because “everlasting” makes it sound like “forever”, thus, would the word “perpetual” be better?

Comment: One may legitimately translate "ad olam" from the verse 30 as until the vanishing point. Moses was a priest and the leader of Israel. His authority was split between Eleazar and Joshua. To have a prophet like Moses (Deuteronomy 18:15), we need that authority united again. When just a generation later, David was writing about the coming priestly king (Psalm 110) and wearing an ephod himself,  he knew what he was doing.

Comment: John the Baptist passed the priestly authority of Levitical priesthood onto Jesus during His baptism.

Answer (score 0):

This is simpler than it appears.  The two are one.

The Aaronic priesthood anticipated and was inherited by Jesus.  The comment in Heb 7:21, 22 is about the nature of Jesus' priesthood compared to the Aaronic priesthood, namely that Melchizedek was a person without genealogy and without death, just like Jesus.

Jesus is now eternal and forever the High Priest of the Covenant.  The Araonic priesthood vanished, but not before it was inherited by Jesus as the book of Hebrews is at pains to point out in many places.

More specifically, Jesus is the high priest of the New Covenant Heb 4:14-16, 5:10, 7:23-28, 8:1, 2, 9:1-28, 10:1-18.  Thus, Jesus inherits and was the fulfilment of the Levitical Covenant (See Mal 3:1).  Jesus did this in several ways as well such as:

- Jesus was the fulfilment of what the sanctuary/temple typified, John 2:19-21, Heb 9:1-28, 10:1-18
- Jesus represented the foundation of the temple as well, 1 Peter 2:4-8 (Compare Isa 28:16, Ps 118:22)
- Jesus’ body was represented by the curtain in the temple, Heb 10:20.
- Jesus was the bread of life, John 6:35, 41, 48 (compare Ex 25:23-30, Lev 24:8).
- Jesus was the light of life, John 8:12, 9:5 (compare the lampstand Ex 25:31-39, Lev 24:3, 4, Isa 53:11, Ps 56:13, etc)
- Jesus provides the water of life, John 4:13, 14 (Compare the laver Ex 30:17-21.  See also 1 Cor 6:11)
- Jesus is the promised seed of the woman Gal 3:16 (compare Gen 3:15, and the Abrahamic Covenant)
- Jesus was the Passover Lamb and thus the promised Messiah, John 1:29, 1 Cor 5:7, 1 Peter 1:19 (compare Ex 12:1-14).
- Jesus is the High Priest of the New Covenant in fulfilment of the Levitical covenant, Heb 4:14-16, 5:10, 7:23-28, because He was “pure, blameless, set apart” exactly as the Levites were.  See also Heb 9:15, 12:24.
- Jesus provided the blood of the new covenant of which the communion ceremony was to be a memorial, Matt 26:28, Mark 14:24, Luke 22:20, 1 Cor 11:25, Heb 13:20, 1 Peter 1:19 (compare Ex 24:5, 8).
- Jesus was the anti-type of the “red heifer” (Num 19:1-10) and its associated ashes that “purify our consciences from works of death”, Heb 9:13, 14.

Answer (score -3):

As with many translations of αἰῶνα aiōna, *eternal* isn't always the most accurate or relevant. "age lasting' or 'age enduring' is often more appropriate.

> Sodom and Gomorrah and the surrounding towns gave themselves up to sexual immorality and perversion. They serve as an example of those who suffer the punishment of eternal fire. Jude v7

Are the fires still burning? No, they have been extinguished long ago - when the fuel was used up the fire went out. The fire was *age-lasting* - once the punishment was executed that 'age' was finished.

> in these last days He has spoken to us by His Son, whom He appointed heir of all things, and through whom He made the universe. Heb 1:2

Again we find,  αἰῶνας· iōnas which is translated universe. Of course universe is not intended, nor is world. 'Ages' is the most appropriate.

The priesthood of Exodus‬ ‭40:15‬, *everlasting priesthood throughout their generations* is similar in that it will last for the age "of their generations". No more is intended - 'eternal' is not appropriate if understood as 'forever and ever'.

Similarly, Jesus' priesthood is for the age it is required - while there are still people who need a High Priest to present them before God. Those who are *already* Christ's need no High Priest - they are already sanctified and made holy IN Christ and have direct access to the Father. Those others who remain and those later to be raised in a resurrection will need a High Priest to offer them salvation and reconciliation.

Comment: I think your takes on the specific question inquired about often have technical merit, but your answers often spin off onto other topics not necessarily related to the question at hand that attract down votes or a lack of upvotes from those who might have otherwise volunteered them. Basically, if you focused on technically answering the specific question without making points on topics (often controversial) not specifically inquired about by the OP you'd meet with more voting success... imho.  I'm often initially inclined to upvote before realizing I can't vote for the rest of your response :)

Comment: In other words, your overall point that eternal may not be the right translation is in my opinion quite right.

Comment: @Austin thanks for your response. What section did you think was unrelated and superfluous. I have given appropriate examples in my view that support the premise.

Comment: honestly, Eternal punishment is controversial and saying Jesus is not an eternal priest is controversial. I think the case is better made from arguing against the Hebrew term in Exodus always meaning eternal as there are definite examples that are not controversial where it cannot possibly always mean eternal. Also, most people on this board are Christians who would more readily accept the end of the Levitical priesthood than the priesthood of Christ. Sometimes the question asked doesn't allow one to avoid controversy. Other times there are ways to make the sound case without it.

Comment: Fair enough, two things. If you think the premise is correct then an UV would cancel one of the DV's and 2, if we wait for an answer - even if biblically responsible, to be *exactly* what we might write, then there would be no UV's at all. What I write may be controversial - anything non-trinitarian, no matter how well exegeted, is controversial here. Again, thanks for your input.